# AppDependencies table is consuming big amount of GB's because MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, serilog, azure-application-insights-profiler

I have a .NET application that ingests lot of data into Log Analytics Workspace in Azure, the AppDependencies table is getting more than 1500 records in a 15 minutes frame, it's getting crazy.
Most of logs look like this:

```
DependencyType: Azure Service Bus
Name: ServiceBusReceiver.Receive

Propierties: {"AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Production","_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors":"(Name:'Dependencies', Ver:'1.1')"}
SDKVersion: dotnetc:2.21.0-429
```

I tried changing the log level in the application from Warning to Error but the problem is the same.
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/azure/sdk/logging#map-to-aspnet-core-logging

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the specific dependencies that you don't want to capture in Application Insights. In your code, before tracking a dependency, check the type and other criteria, and decide whether to track it or not.

- Here I got the same dependency type tracing and had received unnecessary data into my log analytics.

[image]

**Log analytics data:**

[image]

- Filter telemetry at the Telemetry Processor level to further control which telemetry is sent to Application Insights.

```cs
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

var builder = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;
builder.Use((next) => new TelemetryFilterProcessor(next));
builder.Build();

public class TelemetryFilterProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    public TelemetryFilterProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        if (IsErrorOrWarningTelemetry(item))
        {
            this.Next.Process(item);
        }
    }

    private bool IsErrorOrWarningTelemetry(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        // Implement your logic to filter telemetry based on severity
        if (telemetry is ISupportProperties properties)
        {
            if (properties.Properties.TryGetValue("SeverityLevel", out var severityLevel) &&
                Enum.TryParse(severityLevel.ToString(), out LogLevel logLevel))
            {
                // Customize this logic to capture only error and warning telemetry
                return logLevel >= LogLevel.Warning;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here filtered based on custom properties like "SeverityLevel" if your logs include this property.

[image]